# Google на i/o 2013 презентовало Fused location provider, теперь использовать только его?

Tags: java, android, геолокация, gps

Вообще что это за фрукт известно крайне мало и в русскоязычном интернете по ему информации не найти, поэтому все полезные ссылки с вашими комментариями прошу публиковать здесь.

1. И у меня такой вопрос, если надо в приложении под `Android`, брать `GPS` данные раз в 3 минуты и отправлять их на `web`-сервер, то теперь самым разумным способом, получать координаты, будет способ использующий `Fused location provider` или я заблуждаюсь?
2. Вообще было бы здорово если каждый бы высказался о том что он понимает под `Fused location provider` и как его можно использовать.

Comment: > Вообще было бы здорово если каждый бы высказался

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На презентации они четко все описали. Суть в том, что на открытом помоещении gps выдает хорошие координаты, но внутри помещения - ужасные. Но вот использование wifi плюс вышки операторов дает заметно лучший результат gps.

Fused location provider построен на том, что он знает (догадывется), где в данный момент находиться пользователь и выбирает на основании доступной информации правильный источник (или источники) координат.

ответ на 1 пункт. Если ваше приложение к примеру записывает трек автомобилиста, то Вы можете смело продолжать брать координаты от gps. Если же Вы пишиете программу, которая подсказывает пользователю, как перемещатся по большому торговому центру, то тут только Fused.

**upd**

Вся фишка этого нововведения том, что если будет телефон, в котором кроме gps ещё и ГЛОНАСС и [Галилео](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE_%28%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%29), то Fused location provider сможет себе спокойно смешать их вместе и получать хорошие координаты. В противном случае программисту пришлось бы писать кучу кода, что бы свести все вместе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я вообще думал что этот Fused location provider призван взять всю логику получения GPS координат на себя т.е. я ему говорю что мне нужно получать координаты раз в 3 минуты, а он сам уже соображает, как это лучше сделать, с наименьшими потерями электроенергии, я был не прав?

Comment: почему это не правы? все почти правильно. Вы ему говорите в каком виде координаты нужны, а провайдер все подберет для Вас и попытается максимально удовлетворить запрос.